Big O and monotone functions
I'm trying to get a better understanding of big O notation. What I'm wondering about is when we can guarantee that the limit
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$
exists.
It is clear to me that $f(x) = O(g(x))$ is not enough, take for instance $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x$.
This is also not surprising considering that big O is equivalent to
$\displaystyle \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \infty$.
However, my question now is if $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be monotonically increasing functions. Do we then know that the limit exists when $f(x) = O(g(x))$?

NO.  Why not look for an example where $f(x) =O(g(x))$, both monotonically increasing, but $\limsup f(x)/g(x)=5$ and $\liminf f(x)/g(x) = 4$.

Any hints how I find such an example?

Try this
$$
f(x) = x\big(5+\sin(\log x)\big);\qquad g(x) = x
$$
Differentiate to show $f$ is increasing.
Computing $\limsup f/g$ and $\liminf f/g$ are easy.

Thank you. Funnily enough I found the same example last evening, just with $f(x) = e^x(5 + \sin x)$ and $g(x) = e^x$. It seems to me that the problem is when $f$ varies much slower than $g$ grows. I will be posting a new question concerning this observation.
